# Laravel 5.2 : send email via mail DERVER

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I trying to send email from my laravel 5.2 app but never received the email in my inbox

here what I did

env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=myhosting.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=yousef@hosting.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Controller

```
public function html_email(){
        $data = array('name'=>"Data Technology");
        Mail::send('emails.websitePriceRequest', $data, function($message) {
            $message->to('johnef_sh@hotmail.com', 'Data Technology')->subject
            ('Laravel HTML Testing Mail');
            $message->from('johnef_sh@hotmail.com','Data Technology');
        });
        echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
    }
```

after sending the email I get
HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.

but after checking my email noting is there

Comment: Anything special appears in your log files?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$view = 'emails.websitePriceRequest';
$subject = 'Laravel HTML Testing Mail';
$data = array('name'=>"Data Technology");
$email = 'johnef_sh@hotmail.com';
\Mail::send($view, $data, function($message) use($email, $subject)
{
    $message->from('johnef_sh@hotmail.com','Data Technology');
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
});
```